# Vue - partial template

Tags: javascript, templates, vue.js

I got a template in .vue component file. Let's say I need to reuse part of this template (`<img :bind1 :bind2 :bind3`) i need something like this:

```
<a v-if=...><img></a> 
<img v-else>
```

Img is the same part of code here.
What's the best way to do it?

Comment: It's technically the same (`v-else` for the latter), the best way would be to isolate it into a new component

Answer (score 1):

If you need to recreate the same snippet repeatedly the best way is to use a [render function to create a functional component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components). Here's a simple example:

```
Vue.component('my-img', {
  functional: true,
  render: function (createElement, context) {
    return createElement('img', { attrs: { src: context.props.src } })
  },
  props: {
    src: 'http://example.com/img.png'
  }
})
```